# Вывод n(ого) количества изображений(PyQt)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

имеется массив картинок(ссылок на них), надо вывести окно с картинками(по ссылке без скачивания) пространство окна должно вычислять сколько при данном количестве картинок может быть каждая картинка в размере,как любой сайт с видосами,только тут в окне(тобишь нужен вывод именно не по одной сверху вниз,а слева на право все сразу)
нашол только пример такого рода но он я так понял работает только с 1 картинкой,а как изменить код под себя не разобрался:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class URLView(Qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.b('https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2021-01/1611131129_1.jpg',layout)

    def b(self,h,layout):
        self.imageLabel = Qt.QLabel()
        self.imageLabel.setScaledContents(True)
        layout.addWidget(self.imageLabel)

        self.nam = Qt.QNetworkAccessManager()

        print("Load image")

        url = h
        self.nam.get(Qt.QNetworkRequest(Qt.QUrl(url)))

        self.nam.finished.connect(self.finish_request)


    def finish_request(self, reply):
        img = Qt.QPixmap()

        img.loadFromData(reply.readAll())

        self.imageLabel.setPixmap(img)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    w = URLView()
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: daichi, покажите что вы уже успели написать ( [mcve] ). Приведите пример ссылок на изображения и пример названий и т.д.

Comment: daichi, объясните пожалуйста лучше, допустим вы хотите отобразить в вашем окне, которое например имеет размер `800х400`, `три` изображения, ссылки на которые у вас имеются. 1. Покажите как вы хотите видеть ваше окно с этими `тремя` изображениями. 2. Покажите как вы хотите видеть ваше окно с изображениями если их будет не три, а `десять.` 3. Что значит: `не по одной, а все сразу`.

Comment: по моему пример более чем явный и не понятно какие проблемы с пониманием у отвечающих, сам сейчас ответ ищу? Автор у вас получилось?

Answer (score 0):

```
class PictureWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 QNetworkAccessManager - Download Image'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 600
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

    # Create an instance of QNetworkAccessManager
        self.manager = QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.manager.finished.connect(self.onFinished)

    # Create a list of image URLs
        self.urls = ["",
        "",
        ""]

        self.startDownload()

    def startDownload(self):
        self.pix = 0
        self.loadImage(self.urls[self.pix])

    def loadImage(self, url):
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.resize(200, 300)
        self.label.move(self.pix * 200, 0)
        self.pix += 1

        req = QNetworkRequest(url)
        self.manager.get(req)

    def onFinished(self, reply):
        pixmap = QPixmap()
        pixmap.loadFromData(reply.readAll())
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        reply.deleteLater()

        if self.pix < len(self.urls):
            self.loadImage(self.urls[self.pix])
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]